# "Session has expired" Problem in Geoserver as WAR in Tomcat

Tags: geoserver

I have Geoserver installed as WAR in Tomcat. My html/openlayers files are served from the www folder of /webapps/geoserver/data and I had "beautiful moments" experiencing WMS from there.

The problem is this: Each time, after working nicely and smoothly for only minutes, GeoServer user interface becomes too slow and get blocked. When I want to edit sth I get msg like "The session has expired..." So I need then to force the "org.apache.catalina.bootstrap" to quit as it doesn't respond to "/Library/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh" command, then I restart it "/Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh". This didn't happen before, but I don't know what I did that caused such thing.

Also I don't think it's related to WFS because I've tried this and it worked fine:[image]

Comment: I've installed Geoserver via mac installer. where can I find the equivalent to the www folder of Geoserver installed as WAR in tomcat?

Comment: could this be related? http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Sorry-You-session-timed-out-td4965937.html